# Making a Convolutional Neural Network from a flow diagram

Tags: python, image-processing, keras, conv-neural-network, tf.keras

I am trying to make a neural network from a flow diagram. It is necessary for my analysis to translate this network into a code. Could you help me if I'm doing anything wrong. Here is the diagram. The author used binary classification but I'm doing multiple so ignore that one. I'm a kind a new to building CNN and this is all I could come up with different sources from the internet.

[image: Neural Network for wound image classification]

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Conv2D, Concatenate,Dense,Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import BatchNormalization

model_1=Sequential()
#First Stacked
model_1.add(Conv2D(filters=64,kernel_size=7,stride=(2,2),activation='relu',input_shape=(128,128,1)))
model_1.add(BatchNormalization())
model_1.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1))
layer_1=Conv2D(filters=32,kernel_size=3,stride=(1,1),activation='relu')(model_1)
layer_2=Conv2D(filters=64,kernel_size=5,stride=(1,1),activation='relu')(model_1)
layer_3=Conv2D(filters=128,kernel_size=5,stride=(1,1),activation='relu')(model_1)
concatenate_1 = keras.layers.concatenate([layer_1, layer_2,layer_3], axis=1)
#Second Stacked
concatenate_1.add(Conv2D(filters=64,kernel_size=1,stride=(1,1),activation='relu')
concatenate_1.add(BatchNormalization())
concatenate_1.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1))
concatenate_1.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same'))
layer_1=Conv2D(filters=32,kernel_size=1,stride=(1,1),activation='relu')(concatenate_1)
layer_2=Conv2D(filters=64,kernel_size=3,stride=(1,1),activation='relu')(concatenate_1)
layer_3=Conv2D(filters=128,kernel_size=5,stride=(1,1),activation='relu')(concatenate_1)
concatenate_2 = keras.layers.concatenate([layer_1, layer_2,layer_3], axis=1)
#Third Stacked
concatenate_2.add(Conv2D(filters=64,kernel_size=1,stride=(1,1),activation='relu')
concatenate_2.add(BatchNormalization())
concatenate_2.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1))
concatenate_2.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same'))
layer_1=Conv2D(filters=32,kernel_size=1,stride=(1,1),activation='relu')(concatenate_2)
layer_2=Conv2D(filters=64,kernel_size=3,stride=(1,1),activation='relu')(concatenate_2)
layer_3=Conv2D(filters=128,kernel_size=5,stride=(1,1),activation='relu')(concatenate_2)
concatenate_3 = keras.layers.concatenate([layer_1, layer_2,layer_3], axis=1)
#Final
concatenate_3.add(Conv2D(filters=64,kernel_size=1,stride=(1,1),activation='relu')
concatenate_3.add(BatchNormalization())
concatenate_3.add(LeakyReLU(alpha=0.1))
concatenate_3.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same'))
concatenate_3=Flatten()(concatenate_3)
model_dfu_spnet=Dense(200, activation='relu')(concatenate_3)
mode_dfu_spnet.add(Dropout(0.3,activation='softmax'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Concatenate()` is done by doing `Concatenate(**args)([layers])`

```
keras.layers.concatenate([layer_1, layer_2,layer_3], axis=1)
```

should be (note the capitalization)

```
keras.layers.Concatenate(axis=1)([layer_1, layer_2,layer_3])
# axis=1 is default, so you can just do
# keras.layers.Concatenate()([layer_1, layer_2,layer_3])
```

Then do the same for the other `Concatenate()`.

I'm not sure what you want to do with this:

```
model_dfu_spnet=Dense(200, activation='relu')(concatenate_3)
```

But following the picture, that layer should have 32 neurons (seems kinda small for that but idk...)

```
model_dfu_spnet=Dense(32, activation='relu')(concatenate_3)
```

You don't put the activation function on `Droupout`

```
mode_dfu_spnet.add(Dropout(0.3,activation='softmax'))
```

but you probably want it on another `Dense` layer, also with the number of classes as the neurons.

```
mode_dfu_spnet.add(Dropout(0.3))
mode_dfu_spnet.add(Dense(num_of_classes, activation="softmax", name="visualized_layer"))
```

I'm not used to doing Sequential models with Concatenate, usually Functional but it shouldn't be any different.

Comment: First of all thank you so much for making those relevant corrections. Could you please point out me sources where I can learn this through functional way. I will be extremely thankful. Thanks. 
Again thanks for checking the entire thing.

Comment: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/functional

Comment: Thank you, while running it is throwing an error:
 
  File "<ipython-input-5-588eeeb4a371>", line 17

    concatenate_1.add(BatchNormalization())
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Can you update your question with the problem code? SyntaxError can be something as simple as missing parentheses.

Comment: And also the full error with trace?

Comment: Here is the updated one:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72916747/making-a-convolutional-neural-network-from-a-flow-diagram-update-1